# How to set custom weights on a Keras Sequential Model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

So i want to set weights on my own for a `Sequential` keras model. To get the number of weights, i multiplied adjacent layer's node counts by each other.

here is my code:

```
model.add(Dense(units=3, activation='relu', input_dim=4))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))

weights_count = []

weights_count.append(4*3)
weights_count.append(3*3)
weights_count.append(3*5)

weights = []

for count in weights_count:
    curr_weights = []
    for i in range(count):
        curr_weights.append(random.random())
    weights.append(curr_weights)
model.set_weights(weights)
```

This code generates this error:

> ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 2 and 1 for 'Assign' (op: 'Assign') with input shapes: [4,3], [12].

why is this so?

Comment: The model requires the weights not in the vector form ( 12 , ) but in the matrix form ( 4 , 3 ).

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal how do i do that?

Answer (score 8):

The shapes are not aligned.

You might be better off doing something like this:

```py
import numpy as np

# create weights with the right shape, e.g.
weights = [np.random.rand(*w.shape) for w in model.get_weights()]

# update
model.set_weights(weights)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: that works!! however, what do you mean by the shapes aren't aligned?

Comment: Also how can i set random elements to random numbers?